# MobaXterm : Use windows shortcuts in RDP sessions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to MobaXterm and I'd like to use Windows shortcuts in RDP sessions

```
Win + R
Alt + Tab
Alt + F4
...
```

Is there any plugin or option to enable it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working since a recent update (v10)